# Json Get/Send Data Strategies

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, gson

Now I'm learning how to use `Gson` library to set and get data from webservice in `Json` format, but its best practices and strategies are a bit dark for me so I will be very delightful if somebody would explain more about it.

I've created an Entity class to get response entity from server:

```
public class Response
{       
  @SerializedName("Type")
  public String Type;

  @SerializedName("result")
  public String result;

}
```

and in AsyncTask class I've used:

```
Response _Response = new Response();
    try 
    {
        String _url = Global.Url_Request ;

        Map<String, String> Params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Params.put("PhoneNumber", this.User_PhoneNumber);
        String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(Params, Map.class);

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(_url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        HttpResponse getResponse =  httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity returnEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
        is = returnEntity.getContent(); 


        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);

        _Response = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);


    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        _Response.Type= "Error";
        _Response.result= "Data Is Wrong";
    }
    return _Response;
```

It works fine with creating an Entity Object for every different http POST call, but my questions are:

1. What is the best practice for handling webservices with different response objects?
2. How can I handle this situation: if data sent ok then return specific Jsonarray; if   not, return a Response object to detect something is wrong. Should I use Custom typeAdapter?(sample code would be great)
3. If webservice returns an empty response `gson.fromJson` would throw an `**IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT**` how can i prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am always declaring one big dataObject with subclasses of the different Server Responses and can then just the one i need. Or you could just give the asyncclass a class of the response type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. What is the best practice for handling webservices with different response objects?**

I think that this depends on the kind of control you have. If you code also the webservice, you could create a big container object that has may fields. Each of these fields is one of the possible responses you can pass between client and server. If you have not control on what the server can reply, and it can differ a lot, JsonParser is your best friend. You can use it to snoop inside JSON and decide the right strategy to handle the response.

Let's do an example for **case one**. I declare these classes:

```
  public static class GenericResponse{
      public ServerException exception;
      public StandardResponse1 responseType1;
      public StandardResponse2 responseType2;

      @Override
      public String toString() {
         return "GenericResponse [exception=" + exception + ", responseType1=" + responseType1 + ", responseType2=" + responseType2 + "]";
      }

   }

   public static class ServerException{
      public int error;
      public String message;
   }

   public static class StandardResponse1{
      public List<Integer> list;
      public Date now;
   }
```

With this kind of classes, I can parse:

```
{"responseType1":{"list":[1,2],"now":"Nov 25, 2013 9:26:51 PM"}}
```

or

```
{"exception":{"error":-1,"message":"Don\u0027t do this at home"}}
```

For example, if I get from server the second type of response, this code:

```
GenericResponse out = g.fromJson(fromServerStream, GenericResponse.class);
System.out.println(out);
```

will return me:

```
GenericResponse [exception=stackoverflow.questions.Q20187804$ServerException@1e9d085, responseType1=null, responseType2=null]
```

All you have to do is to check your fields to see what actually the server replied.

**Case two**. You cannot control the JSON, so the server can reply

```
[13,17]
```

or

```
{"error":-1,"message":"Don\u0027t do this at home"}
```

In this case you cannot pass directly the class type to Gson as before, but you have to check things. I would solve this problem with a `JsonParser`.

```
      Gson g = new Gson();
      JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
      JsonElement o = jp.parse(s);
      if (o.isJsonArray()){
         List<Integer> list = (List) g.fromJson(o, listType1);
         System.out.print(list);
      }
      else{
         ServerException e = g.fromJson(s, ServerException.class);
         System.out.print(e);
      }
```

Using `JsonObject`/`JsonArray` and so on, is what happens inside a `TypeAdapter`. In the adapter you start with the JsonElement that is already parsed. There are many good example of it on SO, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124387/how-to-use-gson-handle-dynamic-response-data-json-to-java-object) for example.

**How can I handle this situation: if data sent ok then return specific Jsonarray; if not, return a Response object to detect something is wrong. Should I use Custom typeAdapter?(sample code would be great)**

Do you mean you want to parse this kind of response? Examples of point 1 show this.

**If webservice returns an empty response gson.fromJson would throw an  **IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT** how can i prevent this?**

`JsonParser`/`TypeAdapter` is again the solution. You can check if `JsonElement` is null or if is a primitive type (String, Integer, Boolean) and deal it.